# JSON:API fetch reference data

Tags: 9

I have a content type (MealDiary), which contains a reference to a paragraph multiple times (Meal: date, title).
I do get a paragraph uid I can use to retrieve this data, but I would instead like to fetch the field data of the meal withing the MealDiary request.
My goals is 1 request instead of 6.

Anybody could help on this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/fetching-resources-get there are examples to retrieve fields from referenced entities as part of the original request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Paragraphs but I've been doing a lot of work with JSON:API recently.

As noted by @unusedspoon, there are [examples in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/fetching-resources-get#s-get-article-media-entity-reference-field-image-url-uri-by-including-references).

However, using what core provides by default leads to really long queries that aren't much fun to work with.

### Automatically include entity references

Install [JSON:API Extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) and go to `/admin/config/services/jsonapi/resource_types/`.  Select the resource type (entity bundle) you want to automatically include entity references for.  Scroll down to the bottom and edit the **Default include list**.

Note that you can include multiple levels of entity references (for example, to include the file of a media entity: `field_media_audio.file`).

As noted in the UI, if you attach an `include` query string parameter, the default includes will be ignored, so this lets you set useful defaults but then override when necessary.

### Merge entity reference info with the referencing entity

By default, JSON:API returns the entity references separately from the referencing entity.  This might be useful for some people but I find it annoying because I want to access my entity reference data like `myEntity.myEntityReferenceField.value`.  To get this behavior, you can install the [JSON:API Include module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_include).

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborative reply. How can i do the merging part when the paragraph reference has multiple values?

Comment: "JSON:API Include module" did it. Thanks Patrick :)